# Windows 8 sleeps after 1 minute of idle

Tags: windows-8, sleep

When I don't do anything with my laptop for 1 minute (no input, no music playing, ...), it goes to sleep after 1 minute. Not hibernating, just going to sleep with power in RAM. It drives me crazy.

I have a laptop Dell 6410 where I installed Windows 7 but then upgraded to Windows 8 without formatting the hard drive. It's not a corporate laptop under any domain.

The sleep settings are set properly. Balanced mode, going to sleep after 20 minutes on battery and never on power.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't the screen that's turning off to save power?

Comment: both screen and laptop turn off after 1 minute

Comment: Are the power settings handled by Windows or a program offered by Dell?

Comment: By Windows. I uninstalled the Dell power management tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did all I could to fix the problem, finally got remote assistance from
microsoft answer desk. They called it fixed when at their end the computer didn't go to sleep for 3 or 4 minutes. But when the computer was handed back to me, same exact problem. The Third Tech said, "Try changing your microsoft account to a local account. I did that and IT WORKED. I brought my own data over to the local account and I now have a system that works. I occasionally check the Microsoft acct. but it still does the same thing. Don Hayes

Comment: man, you nailed it! :) I haven't had such problem for last couple of months approximately since when I changed my account to local. Thanks for clarifying it!

Answer (score 1):

Check this KB article:

**Monitor powers off after 1 minute when PC is locked**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2835052

Ms posted some powercfg.exe commands to change the time.

Answer (score 0):

If your having the same problem with windows 8 as we are, it going to sleep after 1 min. then having to log in again,  I found a work-around thats not perfect but at least we don't have to log back in every time it goes to sleep.  I just set the Screensaver to start after 1 min. then I just have to move the mouse to get right back to the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

not saying any of the above are wrong, but the problem came up when setting up my new laptop, tried everything everywhere from every geek site I could find and even MS tech s couldn't resolve the problem. If you have Tobi eye tracking installed and enabled it messes with the monitor haha. I disable it if I am note using it. There are a whole bunch of setting in the tobi  software that mess with the screen. cheers
George & the sixpack

Comment: It isn't clear why you think this is a solution in this case.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)