# Is there a way to see which program put windows 10 to sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep, logging

Sometimes my win10 (14393) automatically goes into sleep when I don't touch anything for 2-3 minutes, sometimes it doesn't. I have set the auto sleep to NEVER, I think it is due to some process in the background, is there a way to find out which process put the system into sleep, somewhere under system log perhaps? Thank you.

Comment: Did you check the power settings - extended settings - monitor ?

Comment: It's very unlikely a process is putting your system to sleep.  Typically a process will prevent a system from going into a sleep state

Comment: @GiaRui Yes, I checked, all sleep/monitor related options are setting to NEVER or 1 hour. This auto sleep happens if I don't touch my PC for 3 min, and when I reboot it, the problem is gone, but sometimes, after a while, it comes back, that is why I assume in that time, some process starts to run in the background and leads to this issue

Comment: It's not a process.  If you true believe that. Use AutoRuns to configure an absolute minimum configuration and see if the behavior happens

Comment: Have you looked at your event log(s)?

Comment: May be duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/124772/windows-7-goes-to-sleep-in-conflict-with-power-option-setting or https://superuser.com/questions/606626/windows-8-sleeps-after-1-minute-of-idle

Comment: Is the computer using a battery or alternate current from a socket ?

Comment: Microsoft Community forum: answers to this problem [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-10-keeps-going-into-sleep-after-1-minute/787e8cea-32ce-4ea0-a281-13c32a75352d)

Comment: @spike_66 Thank you! It's working! Can't believe they find this solution! What's the difference between "System unattended sleep timeout" and "Sleep after" anyway.